# "Flipping Card" not working properly on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, mobile-safari

The idea I want is to have a button offset from parent so that when its clicked the card flips. I made the "flip card" animation work on Chrome yet on Safari(Mobile-IOS) there seems to be a "glitch" with the animation where the button gets "cut-off" for a moment making the animation not behave the way I want it (Works as intended on Chrome). I have added the "--webkit-" prefix to the CSS rules that got the animation to work somewhat. Anything I have missed?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  FlipperBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('flipper');
  Array.from(FlipperBtns).forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
      element.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('flip-container')[0].classList.toggle('is-flipped');
    }, false);
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.flipping-frame-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: orange solid 2px;
}

.flipper {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: -30px;
  border: orange solid 2px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.flip-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 60ms;
  position: relative;
}

.is-flipped .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  --webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  --webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.is-flipped .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  --webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flipping-frame-container">
  <div class="flipper"></div>
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="front">Front</div>
    <div class="back">Back</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In two of your css classes, you have used --webkit instead of -webkit. That might be the issue. please check. I only have chrome so can't confirm this, because it's working fine for me.

Comment: I think also perspective needs unit setting, but correcting both of these does not cure the problem.

Comment: @AHaworth thank you for catching those. I am still trying to debug. I have corrected both issues and also found a third "--webkit" yet still not solved.

Comment: Hello @DanielFrausto. Was the problem resolved. I am facing a similar problem.